# Dstat CPU usage for one specific process

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage, measure

Is it possible to measure the CPU and memory for one specific process with dstat? There is possiblilities to measure the most consuming CPU with `--top-cputime` but is it possible to measure a specific one?

I want to write to a file with --output to make a graph of it later, not with ">" operator.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use `command | grep specific_text`

for example test `dstat | grep puppet`

to saving output result in a log file you have two options :

**using --output file**
`dstat --time --cpu --top-cputime --output /tmp/dstat.log | grep puppet`

**using command > file**
`dstat --time --cpu --top-cputime > /tmp/dstat.log | grep puppet`

for appendind logs :
`dstat --time --cpu --top-cputime >> /tmp/dstat.log | grep puppet`

here is [screenshots](http://farshadajdar.com/output.jpg) of both commands

According to your comments may these commands helps you :

(1) save stats in a file  `dstat --time --cpu --top-cputime --output my.log`

(2) apply filtering to log file and save results to file `cat my.log | grep httpd > myhttpd.log`

(3) final results `cat myhttpd.log`

see the screenshot of results [here](http://farshadajdar.com/screenshot2.jpg)

Comment: and if you want to write the content to a file, that wont work: dstat --time --cpu --top-cputime | grep puppet --output filen

Comment: The correct way to write to file is --output file, the > command doesn't write anything to the file.

Comment: check my answer updates and screen shot of both commands working properly !

Comment: Thanks for using your time to help. The problem is that its not writing only the process I am interested into the file. As you can see here:  (https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdgvf8symzd1xja/IMPORTANT.png?dl=0) I am grepping for the process puppet, but in the file into writing other process also. I am only interested in puppet.

Comment: may these commands helps you  :  (1) `dstat --time --cpu --top-cputime  --output my.log` (2) `cat my.log | grep httpd > myhttpd.log` (3) `cat myhttpd.log` see the screenshot http://farshadajdar.com/screenshot2.jpg

Answer (score 10):

No, this is not possible with dstat currently.

I always envisioned to make this possible, but never got around to doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tool!  I'd love to be able to track a specific process as well.